Bootstrapping OIS discount curve from OIS Swaps
I‘m trying to understand why we need Bootstrapping to determine discount factors when we already have the fix rates of OIS Par Swaps. So lets assume that we have the following (annualized) rates:
1 Day  - 3,8%
1 Week - 3,79%
2 Weeks - 3,789%
…
1 Year - 3,5%
Why can‘t we for example use the one year rate directly to determine the 1y discount factor by $\frac{1}{1+3,5%}$
?

D(0,1y) = D(0,6m) x D(6m,12m). I'm arbitrarily using 6m here. But it shows you that to be consistent with other discount factors of differing tenors the 1y df must also incorporate preceding information, where available. This is why the procedure is commonly referred to as bootstrapping.
From this angle, really the 1y rate is telling you, to be consistent with whatever you have computed up till then, what the d(6m,1y) should be. All the preceding information is known.
This way, in an ideal world, for a single currency (implied from instruments of consistent credit quality) you have a single discount curve which can be used to compute the present value of 1 unit of that currency paid at some time in the future.
